# A2070 with a macro in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, masm

I am learning x86 Assembly (MASM32) and I have an issue with macros

For some reason I am getting an error when calling the macro I am getting error A2070

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
ORG 100h
grades db 81h, 65h, 78h, 83h,74h, 57h, 88h, 92h, 51h ,80h ,60h
ORG 500h
minimum db ?
maximum db ?

.code
main proc
MIN MACRO arg1, arg2
MOV esi, arg1
add esi, 1
mov ax, 0
mov al, byte ptr[arg1]
mov ecx, 0
find_min:
CMP byte ptr[esi], 0
je break_min
cmp byte ptr[esi], al
jnb no_change_in_min
mov al, byte ptr[esi]
no_change_in_min:
add esi, 1h
loop find_min
break_min:
mov arg2, al
ENDM

MAX MACRO arg1, arg2
MOV esi, arg1
add esi, 1
mov ax, 0
mov al, byte ptr[arg1]
mov ecx, 0
find_max:
CMP byte ptr[esi], 0
je break_max
cmp byte ptr[esi], al
jna no_change_in_max
mov al, byte ptr[esi]
no_change_in_max:
add esi, 1h
loop find_max 
break_max:
mov arg2, al
ENDM
```

The errors are in this next part

```
mov esi, offset grades
mov edi, offset minimum
MIN esi, edi
mov edi, offset maximum
MAX esi, edi
```

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
A2070 is "invalid instruction operands", I am getting it at the calling of the macros

EDIT2:
I figured it out, I cannot pass a register to a macro, the solution was to pass the label itself to the macro so instead of

```
mov esi, offset grades
mov edi, offset minimum
MIN esi, edi
mov edi, offset maximum
MAX esi, edi
```

it would just be

```
MIN grades, minimum
MAX grades, maximum
```

Thank you!

Comment: Providing the full error message would help; I am guessing most people haven't memorized what all of MASM's numeric error codes mean.

Comment: I did some changes in the code, removed the brackets and its still not working, i edited the original post with the new code and mentioned that A2070 is invalid instruction operands

Comment: I assume the problem is something like `mov arg2, al` . If you use a 32 bit register for arg2 then you can't move an 8 bit register to 32-bit like this. Maybe you could use `movzx arg2, al` to zero extend AL to a larger register.

Comment: Unrelated, but it seems like bad style to define 2 large macros *inside* `proc main`.  And also *highly* questionable to use a bunch of hard-coded registers like ESI.  What if someone uses `MIN esi, edi`, then `esi` and `arg1` are the *same* register, and changes like `add esi, 1` affect `arg1`.  Usually better to take extra macro args for every scratch register you need.  Also, `movzx eax, byte ptr [arg1]` is a better way to do a zero-extending byte load.